# NFS directory is no longer mounted but throws an error in df -h?

Tags: nfs

I have an NFS server (at say, 1.2.3.4), and several clients.

On the clients, I had mounted a local directory by executing:

```
sudo mount 1.2.3.4:/var/nfs/stuff /mnt/nfs/var/nfs
```

All was good until I decided to change the location on the clients to /mnt/nfs. I first unmounted the existing mount point and then remounted the new one:

```
sudo mount 1.2.3.4:/var/nfs/stuff /mnt/nfs
```

No problems with that. And the new mount works fine. But when I run df -h, I get the error:

```
df: ‘/mnt/nfs/var/nfs’: No such file or directory
```

And then it prints the normal mount points. When I execute:

```
mount -t nfs
```

I still see the old (/mnt/nfs/var/nfs) mount point listed, along with the new one. How can I fix this?